# In Corda 3, getting java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /nodes/0/node.conf when running mock nodes

Tags: corda

In Corda 3, I get the following exception when I run the flow tests for the Obligation CorDapp [here](https://github.com/corda/samples):

```
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /nodes/0/node.conf
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:86) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:214) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
    at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:361) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
    at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:407) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
    at java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider.newInputStream(FileSystemProvider.java:384) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
    at java.nio.file.Files.newInputStream(Files.java:152) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
    at net.corda.finance.flows.ConfigHolder.<init>(CashConfigDataFlow.kt:64) ~[corda-finance-corda-3.0.jar:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
    at net.corda.node.internal.AbstractNode.installCordaService(AbstractNode.kt:436) ~[corda-node-corda-3.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.internal.AbstractNode.installCordaServices(AbstractNode.kt:352) [corda-node-corda-3.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.internal.AbstractNode.access$installCordaServices(AbstractNode.kt:103) [corda-node-corda-3.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.internal.AbstractNode$start$4.invoke(AbstractNode.kt:254) [corda-node-corda-3.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.internal.AbstractNode$start$4.invoke(AbstractNode.kt:103) [corda-node-corda-3.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.testing.node.internal.InternalMockNetwork$MockNode$initialiseDatabasePersistence$1.invoke(InternalMockNetwork.kt:317) [corda-node-driver-corda-3.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.testing.node.internal.InternalMockNetwork$MockNode$initialiseDatabasePersistence$1.invoke(InternalMockNetwork.kt:217) [corda-node-driver-corda-3.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.internal.AbstractNode$initialiseDatabasePersistence$2.invoke(AbstractNode.kt:637) [corda-node-corda-3.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.internal.AbstractNode$initialiseDatabasePersistence$2.invoke(AbstractNode.kt:103) [corda-node-corda-3.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.persistence.CordaPersistence.inTopLevelTransaction(CordaPersistence.kt:148) [corda-node-api-corda-3.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.persistence.CordaPersistence.transaction(CordaPersistence.kt:134) [corda-node-api-corda-3.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.persistence.CordaPersistence.transaction(CordaPersistence.kt:120) [corda-node-api-corda-3.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.persistence.CordaPersistence.transaction(CordaPersistence.kt:127) [corda-node-api-corda-3.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.internal.AbstractNode.initialiseDatabasePersistence(AbstractNode.kt:636) [corda-node-corda-3.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.testing.node.internal.InternalMockNetwork$MockNode.initialiseDatabasePersistence(InternalMockNetwork.kt:315) [corda-node-driver-corda-3.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.internal.AbstractNode.start(AbstractNode.kt:205) [corda-node-corda-3.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.testing.node.internal.InternalMockNetwork$MockNode.start(InternalMockNetwork.kt:245) [corda-node-driver-corda-3.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.testing.node.internal.InternalMockNetwork.createNodeImpl(InternalMockNetwork.kt:377) [corda-node-driver-corda-3.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.testing.node.internal.InternalMockNetwork.createNode(InternalMockNetwork.kt:363) [corda-node-driver-corda-3.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.testing.node.internal.InternalMockNetwork.createNode(InternalMockNetwork.kt:358) [corda-node-driver-corda-3.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.testing.node.MockNetwork.createNode(MockNetwork.kt:243) [corda-node-driver-corda-3.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.testing.node.MockNetwork.createNode$default(MockNetwork.kt:243) [corda-node-driver-corda-3.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.examples.obligation.flows.ObligationTests.setup(ObligationTests.kt:28) [classes/:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68) [junit-rt.jar:?]
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47) [junit-rt.jar:?]
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242) [junit-rt.jar:?]
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70) [junit-rt.jar:?]
```

Is this a serious error? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is benign and can be ignored. It will be fixed in Corda 4.